# Entity Framework not binding entity

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following db structure:
[image]

I am using EF6 to create the entities from database and have the following classes created by EF6:

```
  public partial class Mechanic
   {
    public Mechanic()
    {
        this.MechanicAddresses = new HashSet<MechanicAddress>();
        this.MechanicServices = new HashSet<MechanicService>();
    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsMobile { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string FaceBookUrl { get; set; }
    public string TwitterUrl { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuthorised { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationTimestamp { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MechanicAddress> MechanicAddresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MechanicService> MechanicServices { get; set; }
    }


public partial class MechanicAddress
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string MechanicId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationTimestamp { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Latitude { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Longitude { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography Location { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Mechanic Mechanic { get; set; }
}


public partial class MechanicService
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string MechanicId { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }

    public virtual Mechanic Mechanic { get; set; }
}
```

The data is correct so i expect to get data in all entities.

When i run the following linq query in my DAL:

```
Mechanic mech = context.Mechanics.Where(a => a.ID == id).Include(a => a.MechanicAddresses).Include(a => a.MechanicServices).FirstOrDefault();
```

It returns the mechanic and mechanicAddresses but mechanicServices is always empty (count == 0).

When i run the same query in LinqPad I get all entities filled as expected.

I have removed the edmx and re-created it but still get the same issue.

Comment: Check the SQL generated by EF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: Thanks Steve, already done that, I ran profiler to get the actual query executed. the SQL joins the tables as expected and when i run it against the DB the data is in the result. It's just not getting from the result to the entity model.

Comment: Does var mechService = context.MechanicServices.Where(a => a.MechanicId == id).FirstOrDefault(); return a result?

Comment: Hi Steve, yep, strangely it does. I have managed to fix this as per the answer i've added below but it's never best to have to regenerate the SQL table and EDMX. oh well it is fixed (for now.). Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i was able to resolve this was to:

- delete the EDMX
- script the create for the mechanicsServices table
- script the data
- drop the mechanicsServices table
- run the create table script from above
- run the insert data script
- regenerate the EDMX

This now works, WTF! Can't explain it.

I know it's always best to understand what went wrong but this one beat me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if "MultipleActiveResultSets" is set to true and LazyLoadingEnabled is enabled in connection string. It may help.

Comment: Hi Dreamweaver, 

MultipleActiveResultSets is True in connection string.

The linQ is using 'include' which specifies i want eager loading not lazy.

I have written 100's of linQ queries using EF6 and never had this issue, the fact that it works fine in LinqPad and not through EF tells me that this is EF related but the DB structure and entities look sound to me.

Answer (score 0):

And what about your OnModelCreating?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

It's not necessary to use Include if you have LazyLoading (virtual). And If it works fine in LinqPad try to do migration into empty DB (just test). And then try to get data from test DB.

Comment: Thanks Alexander but i've already migrated the DB and tested and same thing. For some reason it doesn't get the MechanicsServices but it will quite happily get all other relationships. somethings up with the way EF is fixing this up. I just can't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

If you using git, please check .edmx file old version. **SSDL content** may be missing.